# Creating IPA for TestFlight, Developer ID

Tags: testflight

I am quite new to Xcode 4.3 and whenever I try to compile my project to the IPA format needed for TestFlight it asks me for a Developer ID, is the only way to get this to pay the $99/year charge?

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: this was posted in 2012 lol

Comment: oops ok it said I should edit a question to get a trophy thing so i added and exclamation mark haha ö-ö, my bad

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need the subscription in order to roll out to (non-jailbroken) devices. Without the subscription you can only test in the simulator.